# Use .match output in a new match

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

```
var myMatch1 
var myMatch2
```

are the outputs of a .match. The matches come out as word, word, word

I want to use

```
var newMatch1 = new RegExp(myMatch1, "gi"); 
var newMatch2 = new RegExp(myMatch2, "gi"); 

document.write(newMatch1.exec(newMatch2));
```

However this will only do an exact match. I really want the `newMatch1` and `newMatch2` to be expressed (/word|word|word/gi), (i.e to match *any* found words).

How would I write var newMatch to do this?

**edit:** vars `myMatch1` and `myMatch2` aren't arrays, they are literally found keyword matches from URLs. Any matches found are expressed as `word1, word2, word3`. I need to use those matches in another match hence the use of vars `newMatch1` and `newMatch2`. I don't want to express those words in the `new RegExp` as `word1, word2, word2`, they need to be expressed as `word1|word2|word3`.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused... are `myMatch1` and `myMatch2` arrays? Do you meant to write `var newMatch2 = new RegExp(myMatch2, "gi");` (note the `2`). If yes, what do you expect the outcome of `newMatch1.exec(newMatch2)` to be? Since you are trying to execute a regular expression not on a string but another expression...  believe an example with actual values and your expected outcome would help a lot to understand the problem.

Comment: @FelixKling  Sorry typo, it's supposed to be a 2 (edited). I expect the outcome of newMatch1 and newMatch2 to match any words that are the same. myMatch1 and myMatch2 will only return true if "Queen, Wands" are written exactly the same, However I need it match two words if myMatch1 is Queen, Wands, Coins, and myMatch2 is Queen, Wands, Swords.

Comment: So it seems all you need to do is replace `, ` with `|`? `myMatch1 = myMatch1.replace(/,\s*/g, '|');`. `newMatch1.exec(newMatch2)` still doesn't make sense though.

Comment: Yes. Should have just said that! I will go and try that out.

Comment: @FelixKling I had to convert it to a string first (it was an array after all sorry) but your solution was spot on - Thanks.

Comment: If it is an array, then you can just do `myMatch1 = myMatch1.join('|')`... much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to understand, but you can use string concatenation and the `RegExp` constructor to build your regex

```
 var re = new RegExp( myMatch1 + '|' + myMatch2, 'gi' );
 var newMatch = str.match( re );
```